# JSON - msg.d is undefined error

Tags: jquery, serialization, webmethod

Webmethod returns an array of objects - something like this

```
{"d":
[[{"Amount":100,"Name":"StackOverflow"},
{"Amount":200,"Name":"Badges"},
{"Amount":300,"Name":"Questions"}]]}
```

On the client-side, when the JSON is referenced using msg.d, I get a

```
msg.d is undefined
```

error. I am using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2

How do I access the elements in the array of objects?

---

Adding more findings, code and questions:

1. I don't see __type in the JSON object that is returned. Does that mean that the object sent from the server is not JSON formatted?
2. When the __type is not a part of the response, I will not be able to use msg.d? (msg.d is undefined)

---

Some more:
1. I can access the elements from client side using
msg[0][0].Amount - How can I specifically JSON format my return object (from the server)

---

**Code**
Call to the PageMethods

```
PageMethods.BuildParticipantAsync($get('<%=hdn_AjaxControls.ClientID %>').value, fOnSuccess, fOnFailure);

function onSuccess(msg)
{
alert(msg.d); //This is undefined
}

Web Method
public static object[] BuildParticipantAsync(string lstSAjaxControls)
{
...//do stuff
 return new object[] { ArrayOfObject };
}
```

Comment: Is this after an ajax request? Are you sure the return object is JSON formatted?

Comment: lets see your jquery code please.

Comment: are you sure JSON is in corrent format?

Comment: @czarchaic: That's the response I get after a AJAX request.

Comment: @Shoaib Shaikh: It looks like. Doesn't it? When passing an array of objects from webmethods, I 
    return new object[] { ArrayOfObjects };

Comment: Maybe a server-side serialization issue? You may want to add the following tags to your question: "webmethods" "json" "serialization"

Comment: once again. lets see your jQuery code.

Comment: @David Murdoch: Edited to add code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys, here's what I found. Because, I am returning back a object[] and not a composite object of a class. I will not be able to reference using msg.d[0].Amount (as I thought I would be able to). I will have to use msg[0][0].Amount - In a way, it does seem to make a lot of sense.